# Why is my computer listed twice in my network on two different ip's one ending in .255?

Tags: networking, security

My computer is listed twice on the network (same MAC address and description) with one IP ending in .255, which leads me to believe I may being spoofed.  Is this route table unusual?

[image]

I'm not really sure if software exists out there to detect these kind of things but I would appreciate any help offered.

**added by barlop**

see the duplicate MAC interface.

[image]

Comment: the following  is not an issue, but you say one IP ending in .255? I see more than one IP ending in 255.

Comment: What networking scanning tool did you use there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by listed twice "on the network"?  What are the two IPs?  There's nothing wrong with that route table - looks completely standard to me.

- 127.0.0.1 is your [loopback address](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/loopback_address.html)
- 192.168.0.0 is the [network address](https://serverfault.com/questions/135267/what-is-the-network-address-x-x-x-0-used-for)
- 192.168.0.6 is your IP
- 192.168.0.255 is the [broadcast address](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/2384/broadcast-address) for your network

You only have 1 MAC address listed (the one ending in AE DC) - the one ending in 00 e0 is a virtual NIC used for ipv4 to ipv6 conversion.

There is nothing wrong with your network adapter, it hasn't been spoofed and the entries in the screenshot you posted only show a single machine.

Comment: Hi Fazer,  please refer to this image from a networking scanning tool I have.    http://imgur.com/M8gdxOD this same IP 192.168.0.255 is in my route table too

Comment: aaron - see edited, updated answer

Comment: Hi Fazer, thanks for the update.  I mistakenly posted the same image to you twice.  If you don't mind explaining to someone with not much experience in networking why I would have the same MAC address as the broadcast address on the network?  Much appreciated!  http://imgur.com/FlD6Yuc

Comment: When your machine sends a "broadcast" - it is not actually sent to a specific device, but to all devices.  The first machine that repies is probably being logged (or the software you are using is just using your MAC since there is no broadcast mac".  try pinging 192.168.0.255 and you'll see that teh reply can come from anywhere

Comment: either way its defintely nto spoofed as 192.168.0.255 will not work as a valid IP address on a network with a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask.

Comment: Hi Fazer, when I pinged that address I got a "General Failure" and no response not the typical "destination host unreachable".  Thanks for ur help so far btw

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.. odds are your ping is going out over ipv6 by default.. its really nothing to worry about.

Comment: @aaronrockerfella You write `please refer to this image from a networking scanning tool I have. imgur.com/M8gdxOD`  <-- That is exactly the same image as is in your question, and I can assure you he has heard of netstat.  It's not some random nameless tool

Comment: @barlop... take a look just below that.. there was an apology and updated image link which made a lot more sense :)

Comment: @Fazer87 ah ok. I agree there's no danger but he asks an interesting question re the broadcast MAC. You write "there is no broadcast mac"  <-- But there is. It is, `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` try googling broadcast mac address   There wouldn't be one for a particular IP subnet  But I suppose an IP broadcast wouldn't cross subnets anyway. So, a question would be why is the MAC address that individual interface's MAC and not FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF

Comment: Thats down to the code of the application running the scan.  ARP -a will give you the ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff address, so this will be a programatic choice of whoever wrote the tool.  You wouldn probably see something similar for 255.255.255.255 if found on a scan

Comment: @Fazer87 It's funny that it even lists a broadcast address among the interfaces though so does arp -a so I guess the broadcast is a virtual interface..   Maybe the tool sent a broadcast out with (incorrectly I suppose) the MAC address of one of the interfaces.  Either way, I think the tool he is using has put in the wrong MAC address for the broadcast IP

Answer (score 0):

More clearly, to specifically address the concept for future readers, the .255 address in this particular class of network (/24) is the **broadcast address** and is a special address used by **all** computers on the network.

When a message is sent to 192.168.0.255, it is sent to every device and they can all respond. The router generates the devices table by recording these responses along with the IP and MAC of the responding device. Devices *should* respond using their *own* IP address and not the broadcast address.

**In this particular case, either a dumb router or a dumb piece of software is causing an erroneous entry to show up**. It is nothing to worry about, but also shouldn't be there, as it is a software bug.

Most likely an application on the computer has bound the 192.168.0.255 address or is sending traffic with 192.168.0.255 as the *source* address.

Comment: could it be the network scanning software itself has sent a broadcast to 192.168.0.255 with the wrong mac address?  Is it possible for it to be software on the computer running the network scanner?  It'd be interesting to see if doing that messes up the ARP table in every computer.   Is there a quick way e.g. any command line utility you know of that can be run from linux/cygwin, to spoof a source IP and MAC as a test?

Comment: @barlop: Could be anything. But routers usually map their device tables based on source address though some may use the same mechanism as ARP and get confused by any device that responds to the broadcast address (which is just retarded).

Comment: @barlop: Maybe netcat or http://packeth.sourceforge.net/packeth/Home.html depending on how extreme you want to go.